# Should the seals and pistons in a new caliper be flush with the caliper body?

Tags: brakes, disk-brakes

I bought a remanned front brake caliper from advance auto parts and the seals  and pistons are out about 3/8 inch. Should the seals and pistons be flush with the caliper body? [I'm inclined to say YES! The new rotors and pads are thick and the caliper should give clearance for those parts.] 
Currently one of the pistons is touching the rattle shield or whatever you call it.

I'm going to swap this caliper because I rebuilt a caliper before for a ranger and got everything nice and flush. I think this is just a job poorly done. Am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: so push them in if needed (??).

Comment: What are these calipers for (make/year/model)? Most calipers will, some won't. You probably didn't check, but were your original calipers flush when compressed?

Comment: The new calipers are more than likely good. I'd suspect they just weren't collapsed the entire way when rebuilt. This isn't a shoddy job, just how they were put together. With them being out a little ways, there's no pressure on any of the internal parts. It's the way I'd do it if I were refurbing them to get put on a shelf for an unknown period of time.

Comment: The seals and pistons on the passenger side are flush, both on the caliper thats on the truck now and the remanned one I got. The drivers side seal is flush but the piston is frozen way out. I have a 1997 ranger sport with rwd and rw abs

Comment: @Paul Hm I didn't think about that. Do you have an opinion about the piston touching the rattle guard? (Thats what Ive been calling it, I mean that springy metal piece that the pads touch

Comment: @agentp I guess I would have tried that but I'm home now and all I have here are sockets. I usually go to a cool local makerspace to do these projects.

Comment: @Paul but now that I give it another thought I wouldnt worry too much about pressure because the only parts to these calipers are the pistons and the seals. I think the calipers on my old acura had more complicated internals for retracting the pistons. I think on the integra I had to rotate the pistons to put them in / out and there may have been some internal mechanism for that. Also those were rear calipers so they probably had some hardware for the emergency brake.

Comment: No, pistons always protrude out from the casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your picture does not show enough detail, but I think that the item you call the seal is actually the rubber dust cover and the pressure seals are further back on the piston.

Also you should be able to push the pistons back flush with the body - take care some pistons need to be rotated either clockwise or anticlock due to the mechanism inside, the pistons only need to go back sufficiently to allow new pads to be fitted.

Comment: your right mike the oil seal is inside I misspoke. That is the dust seal thats sticking  out. These calipers have no internal mechanism that requires rotation. I'm heading out now to try and stick it on. Im just concerned that if the pro in the shop couldnt get the piston in fully maybe there was a mechanical reason. You've all put my mind at ease. Im just going to try and put it on now and hope it fits, otherwise Ill find a way to try and push it in farther.

Comment: As long as the pistons move, then all is fine - push them back flush and fit the pads & discs as necessary

Comment: Ive asked this maybe dumb question just to get some insight from people with  more experience to see if there are details Ive overlooked. Thanks for your input

Comment: When you push them back, use something flat and wide (I have used a cold chisel as a lever : flat wide but no hammers !! ) - a screwdriver can slip and puncture the dust shield.